# What is the value assigned to num in the statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the value assigned to num in the statement:  double num = 5/2;?

Some websites say 2 some say 2.5. Help please.

Comment: Did you try `double num = 5/2;` then `cout << num` ?

Comment: Can you post the URL of the website that says it is 2.5?

Comment: What was the value when you tried it? You do realize that it would have taken you less time and effort to just type that code into an editor and try it out than type it into your browser and create a question out of it … let alone the time you'll have to wait for an answer.

Comment: 2 words: _integer division_.

Answer (score 1):

`double num = 5/2;` gives 2 as result.

`double num = 5/2.0;` or `double num = 5.0/2.0;` or `double num = 5.0/2;` gives 2.5 as result.

You better try the codes on your own. Ask questions when you alone are not able to think/work enough. This way you learn more.

Answer (score 1):

```
double num = 5/2;
```

In most cases, each expression, even if it's a subexpression of a larger expression, is evaluated on its own. The type and value of the result are determined by the (sub)expression itself, not by the context in which it appears.

In the expression `5/2`, the division operator has two operands, both of type `int`, so it yields a result of type `int`. (There are languages in which integer-by-integer division yields a non-integer result. C++ is not one of those languages; neither is C.)

The result of `5/2` is `2` (because integer division truncates). That value is converted to the type of `num` and used to initialize it, so the initial value of `num` is `2.0`. (`2` and `2.0` are distinct; they have the same mathematical value, but different types, namely `int` and `double`. That's why the implicit conversion is necessary.)

If you wanted `num` to have the value `2.5`, there are several ways you could do it:

```
double num = (double)5 / (double)2;
double num = (double)5 / 2;
double num = 5.0 / 2.0;
double num = 2.5;
```

In the second example, the left and right operands are of different types, so they're converted to a common type via some moderately complicated rules. In this case, the `int` operand is converted to `double`.

I generally prefer to use floating-point constants rather than integer constants in floating-point expressions (`5.0` rather than `5`). In *some* cases an integer constant will be converted to floating-point as needed, but as we've seen here that applies more to individual literals than to constant expressions.

Comment: Wow. Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

`num` is of datatype `double`. Therefore, it will save a floating point value.
However, it also depends upon what you assign to it.
You are currently assigning it with an integer value. `5/2 = 2`.
Thus, `num` will be assigned `2` and internally it will be saved as `2.0`.

If you want num to have 2.5, then convert it to a floating point value before to assign.
`num = 5.0 / 2` | `num = 5.0 / 2.0` | `num = 5 / 2.0` wil result in `num = 2.5`